# How to create a dictionary from a list of dictionary using specific keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to extract specific keys:values from a list of dictionary and then create a 'new dictionary' in Python.

I know how to create a 'new dictionary' from a single dictionary (extracting keys 'a' and 'c' and their associated values):

```
# Single dictionary
d1 = {"c": 3, "a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 4}
d11 = dict((i, d1[i])
           for i in ["a", "c"] if i in d1)
print(d11)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

But if I have a list of dictionary like this:

```
# List of dictionary
d2 = [{"c": 3, "a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 4},
      {"a": 100,  "c": 300, "b": 200, "d": 400},
      {"b": 'Ball', "c": 'Cat', "d": 'Doll', "a": 'Apple'}]
```

How can I extract and output the keys 'a' and 'c' and their associated values like this:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 100, 'c': 300}, {'a': 'Apple', 'c': 'Cat'}]
```

I have tried this:

```
d22 = dict((k, d2[k])
           for k in ["a", "c"] if k in d2)
```

But it returns an empty dictionary:

```
{}
```

Comment: The result is a list...

Comment: @Mad Physicist - I think you voted negative because I mentioned the result is an 'empty dictionary'. As of my knowledge, when the result returned '{}', it is an empty dictionary NOT an empty list, which should be '[]'. Please enlighten.

Comment: Downvote not mine. I just meant that you're asking for a list in one sentence but getting a dictionary in the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
d2 = [{"c": 3, "a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 4},
      {"a": 100,  "c": 300, "b": 200, "d": 400},
      {"b": 'Ball', "c": 'Cat', "d": 'Doll', "a": 'Apple'}]

filter_list = ["a", "c"]

d22 = [{k: d[k] for k in filter_list} for d in d2]
print(d22)
```

Print:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 100, 'c': 300}, {'a': 'Apple', 'c': 'Cat'}]
```